# How to fix Node interpreter can't been found by intellij, but the node file is in the folder

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, npm, fedora-29

Intellij can't find my Node.js. If I add it locally the node file isn't visible, but in my file manager node is visible. How can I fix this?

[image: node executable not found in $PATH]

[image: node & nodejs are both in the folder]

[image: Intellij can't find the file in the correct folder]

[image: node verions]

I am on Fedora 29. I can run Node.js in my terminal, so I know it is there. Already tried to link the node file with the Node.js file in the terminal. I also tried to run node in visual studio code, but it seems not to work.

I installed node.js and npm with the following command:

```
 $ sudo dnf install npm nodejs
```

I expected that a re-installation and a reboot was going to fix it. But Intellij seems not to keep the node file invisible for me.

Comment: looks like node is not on your `$PATH`. Please try starting IDEA from terminal using idea.sh script - does the issue persist?

Comment: @lena I fixed it after deleting fedora and installing ubuntu!

Comment: I am facing the same issue on wsl ubuntu. Intellij does not show my node file that is on wsl folder and I can't configurate this. Any help?

Comment: @YouJin, I have fixed it by using Webstorm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case running this command fixed the issue.

```
ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/local/bin/node
```

The problem is that I need to run this command anytime I Install a new Node version from NVM.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as OP in 2022. I used your solution, but not even /usr/local appears in the File dialog for me.

Comment: I restarted my computer and started getting the OPs problem. Can confirm running this command in the Terminal instantly fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the same **Problem** in 2023 check that you **haven't** installed IntelliJ via the **fedora flathub** (so it's a flatpack).
This version is the default in the fedora Store.

*It seals the installation in a "sandbox", so it can't access other programs to prevent harm. This leads to IntelliJ not finding node, npm, xmp and corepack.*

To get a **working version of IntelliJ on Fedora 36/37** and probably also older versions install the snap version.

1. Uninstall the flatpack
2. Install snap (https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-fedora)

   ```
   sudo dnf install snapd
   sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
   ```
3. Install IntelliJ Ultimate (https://snapcraft.io/install/intellij-idea-ultimate/fedora)

   ```
   sudo snap install intellij-idea-ultimate --classic
   ```

OR

3. Install IntelliJ Community Version (https://snapcraft.io/install/intellij-idea-community/fedora)

   ```
   sudo snap install intellij-idea-community --classic
   ```

Comment: I used the snap Package of node `sudo snap install node --classic`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is very sinister if you are unaware that flatpack apps have a different root directory.

You can fix it without resorting to snaps by selecting node from /run/host/... which is where you should be able to see the host filesystem (if not install Flatseal and enable "All system files" for the IDE).

[image]

However in my case it didn't seem to fully work after, as I still get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I reinstalled node from https://nodejs.org/en/ and reopened intellij.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30075842)